# Groovy dynamic variables' value

Tags: groovy

I have a groovy script as given below. I have defined a list which contains dynamic variables. The dynamic variables hold different values. how do i print the values of the variables - I don't want to hardcode `this.var0`. Please help.

```
someList = []

for (i in 0..2) {
    someList[i] = "var${i}"
}

var0 = "test1"

// print the values of the variables in the list
println this.someList[0]
```

Comment: You have a list of interpolated strings, those are different than declaring variables.

Answer (score 1):

The value from `someList[0]` has to be interpolated as well. Try:

```
println this."${someList[0]}"
```